# Change NULL value to another value in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, database

I have 3 tables. ID and Name is the primary key for the first table.

**First Table**

```
ID | Name | Date
----------------
1  | AA   | 11/02
2  | BB   | 04/10
```

ID, Name and Option are the primary key for second table:

**Second Table**

```
ID | Name | Option  | SeqNo
---------------------------
3  |  DD  |   LOVE  | 1
4  |  EE  |  SINGLE | 1
```

Option is the primary key for the third table:

**Third Table**

```
Option | Status
---------------
LOVE   |  Y
MARRIED|  Y
SINGLE |  N
```

After I join these tables, I will get like this.

```
ID | Name | Option | SeqNo | Status
------------------------------------
1  | AA   | NULL   | NULL  | NULL
2  | BB   | NULL   | NULL  | NULL
3  | CC   | LOVE   |   1   |  Y
4  | DD   | SINGLE |   1   |  N
```

My **question** is, how to change the NULL value to a value contain in another table?

As an **example**, The Option column must be filled in with the value inside the third table.  I'm using SQL Server 2005

Comment: Please show the syntax you are using to perform the JOIN that generates the results

Comment: What is relation between table one and two?

Comment: SELECT t1.*,  t2.Option, t2.SeqNo, t3.Status

FROM Table1 AS t1

LEFT JOIN Table2 AS t2

ON t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.Name = t1.Name
LEFT JOIN Table3 AS t3
ON t3.Option = t2.Option
</pre>

Answer (score 2):

This link describes how to replace null values in different sql engines, including sql server - 
http://www.sqlines.com/oracle/functions/nvl
Basically, the syntax you are looking for is -

```
ISNULL(SeqNo, 'N/A')
```

Comment: If I want to replace NULL value with multiple value, do I need to duplicate the syntax? @Yaron

Comment: This is not your original question, and also not a very clear requirement. First - if this answer your question, please accept the answer.